# simplecart:need to pass another params on checkout

Tags: javascript

I need to pass item id through checkout on custom form. Here is item add

```
<div class="simpleCart_shelfItem">
  <div class="ju_cntr" style="width:350px">
    <input type="hidden" class="item_id" name='tratata' value="asfd2">
    <div class="juice_hd item_name" style="width:350px">
       test2
    </div>
    <div class="juice_pic" style="width:350px">
      <img class="item_thumb item_image item_add" src="/images/upload/9174.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="juice_txt">
      <span class="item_price">$123.00</span><input type="text" value="1" class="item_Quantity"><a class="item_add" href="javascript:;"> Add to Cart </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and result on checkout

```
Array
(
    [currency] => USD
    [shipping] => 0
    [tax] => 0
    [taxRate] => 0
    [itemCount] => 2
    [item_name_1] => 
                                            123                                     
    [item_quantity_1] => 7
    [item_price_1] => 123
    [item_options_1] => 
    [item_name_2] => 
                                            test2                                       
    [item_quantity_2] => 6
    [item_price_2] => 123
    [item_options_2] => 
)
```

Does anybody know how can I do that? Thanks!

Here is documentation http://simplecartjs.org/documentation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the additional item data is passed inside the item_options_n element.

So in your case it should be:

```
[item_name_1] => 
                                        123                                     
[item_quantity_1] => 7
[item_price_1] => 123
[item_options_1] => 
[item_name_2] => id: <your_id_here>
                                        test2                                       
[item_quantity_2] => 6
[item_price_2] => 123
[item_options_2] => id: <your_id_here>
```

If not, may be it doesn't grab the values from form elements. In that case you would have to get them manually.